# mongod rs.initiate() error msg

Tags: mongodb, replica-set

I am a newbie so please bear with me.
I have used this command `$ sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod2.conf`in terminal to start a mongodb service instance.  In another terminal I ran `$ mongo --port XXXX` where XXXX is the port number I configure in ***mongod.conf*** file.  **rs.initiate()** in mongo shell is giving the error  `"errmsg" : "assertion src/mongo/db/repl/replset_commands.cpp:275",
    "code" : 8`
why ?

edit:
`**mongodb version v3.2.12**`
*mongod2.conf file consist of:*

`# for documentation of all options, see:`
`# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/`
`# Where and how to store data.`
`storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb2
  journal:
    enabled: true`
`#  engine:`
`#  mmapv1:`
`#  wiredTiger:`
`# where to write logging data.`
`systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb2/mongod.log`
`# network interfaces`
`net:
  port: 27019
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

`processManagement:
  fork: true`
`#security:`
`#operationProfiling:`
`replication: 
  replSetName: myDevReplSet`

Comment: Hi Prakhar Gajbhiye, and welcome to the site. It's hard to tell what might be going wrong, so could you provide some more info? What version of MongoDB are you running, and can you show us what's in that mongod2.conf file?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I am able to use replica set now.
 I created multiple copy of `mongod.conf` naming `mongod1.conf` , `mongod2.conf` and so on  in which I specified `dbpath` as `/var/lib/mongodb1`, `/var/lib/mongodb2` and so on _(as you can see in the edit section of mongod2.conf)_  and it works fine. 
Apology  if there is something naive.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem. The best thing to do here is to [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and then [accept](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) it - that will take your question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created multiple copy of `mongod.conf` naming `mongod1.conf` , `mongod2.conf` and so on in which I specified `dbpath` as `/var/lib/mongodb1`, `/var/lib/mongodb2` and so on (as you can see in the edit section of `mongod2.conf`) and it works fine.If there doesn't exist folder `/var/lib/mongodb1` then it automatically creates it or you should just create the folder. Now you can use replica set.